# how to make a Hovmuller plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, latitude-longitude

I have 12 matrices containing numbers from 0 to 99. Each matrix is 1446x1124 double and correspond to a month. I have also latitude and longitude matrices each one is also 1446x1124. I would like to know how to make a Hovmuller plot (Longitude vs time plot or latitude vs time plot) which represents the occurences of a given number between 0 and 99 over the 12 matrices.

Comment: Perhaps this can be usefull? http://ecco2.jpl.nasa.gov/data1/cube/cube76/matlab/hovmuller.m~

Comment: Thank you. But I could not figure out a solution from this. I'm wondering if i can use a simple function like "contour" or "surf"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have a 12x100 matrix `M` with in each field the number of occurences, plotting them is quite straightforward.

```
M = rand(12,100);
plot(M) % Plots 100 lines
plot(M') % Plots 12 lines
plot(sum(M)) % Plots the sum of 100 lines
plot(sum(M')) % Plots the sum of 12 lines
contour(M) % Gives the contour plot
surf(M) % Gives the surface plot
```

In case you do not know how to create M, I will only give the hint that it should not be too hard with 2 for loops.

Comment: how exactly is your answer related to the question?

Comment: @Shai Given the comment I am trying to help the asker to plot his data. I assumed the hovmuller was not a hard requirement.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thank you for your answer. Indeed it is quite easy when you try to use the contour function. I m trying to create the matrix. That's the job !

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [contourf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html). The trick is in sampling the 3D arrays appropriately:

```
x=linspace(0,pi,20);
y=linspace(0,pi,10);
t=0:10:120;
[X3d,Y3d,T3d]=meshgrid(x,y,t);
[X2d,T2dx]=meshgrid(x,t);
[Y2d,T2dy]=meshgrid(y,t);

dat3d=7*sin(X3d)+5*cos(Y3d)+T3d/max(T3d(:))+rand(size(X3d));
dat2dx=7*sin(X2d)+5*cos(y(5))+T2dx/max(T2dx(:))+rand(size(X2d)); % at y(5)
dat2dy=7*sin(x(12))+5*cos(Y2d)+T2dy/max(T2dy(:))+rand(size(Y2d));  % at x(12)
%%
figure(1);clf
contourf(X2d,T2dx,dat2dx);
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)')
xlabel('X distance (km)')
%%
figure(2);clf
contourf(Y2d,T2dy,dat2dy);
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)')
xlabel('Y distance (km)')
%%
figure(3);clf
subplot(221)
contourf(squeeze(X3d(5,:,:)),squeeze(T3d(5,:,:)),squeeze(dat3d(5,:,:)));
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)'); xlabel('X distance (km)')
title('Hovmoller at y(5)')
subplot(222)
contourf(squeeze(Y3d(:,12,:)),squeeze(T3d(:,12,:)),squeeze(dat3d(:,12,:)));
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)'); xlabel('Y distance (km)')
title('Hovmoller at x(12)')
subplot(223)
contourf(squeeze(X3d(8,:,:)),squeeze(T3d(8,:,:)),squeeze(dat3d(8,:,:)));
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)'); xlabel('X distance (km)')
title('Hovmoller at y(8)')
subplot(224)
contourf(squeeze(Y3d(:,17,:)),squeeze(T3d(:,17,:)),squeeze(dat3d(:,17,:)));
shading flat; colorbar
ylabel('Time (days)'); xlabel('Y distance (km)')
title('Hovmoller at x(17)')
```